# what happen if one job in a laravel queue batch, failed?

Tags: laravel

I want to process some queued jobs in a batch, I have a little question.
laravel try to process next job or close whole batch, when one job in batch is failed?
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#batch-failures

```
$batch = Bus::batch([
    new FirstJob(),
    new SecondJob(),
    new ThirdJob(),
    new FourthJob(),
    new LastJob(),
])->then(function (Batch $batch) {
    // All jobs completed successfully...
})->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
    // First batch job failure detected...
})->finally(function (Batch $batch) {
    // The batch has finished executing...
})->dispatch();
```

for example if **FourthJob()** is going to fail, batch will try **LastJob()** or not?

Answer (score 1):

`LastJob()` will not execute by default.
When a job within a batch fails, Laravel will automatically mark the batch as "cancelled". If you wish, you may disable this behavior so that a job failure does not automatically mark the batch as cancelled. This may be accomplished by calling the allowFailures method while dispatching the batch:

```
$batch = Bus::batch([
    // ...
])->then(function (Batch $batch) {
    // All jobs completed successfully...
})->allowFailures()->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch execution can continue to try `lastJob()` based on whether you have set the `batch` to accept `failures` or `not`.

Comment: Tank you,
Do you mean `LastJob()` will not execute by default ?